# Deserializing json string into generic class

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have this JSON string coming in from a form, in there I have key-value pairs (the regular json), but I don't know what keys will come in. I want to get all the key-value pairs there, loop them, then create a row in my database for each of them. That row basically just has "[ID, fkId, Label, Value]", both Label and Value are strings.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to parse that json string to get the info I want. Currently I don't care about nested json strings, I might handle those later / differently.

Comment: Have you looked into [this](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON)? Even though it's made for Unity, I think you could still use it for other purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just deserialize to a `Dictionary<string, string>`, like this:

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

var fieldsValues = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(@"{""A"":""B"", ""AX"":""BX""}");
// fieldsValues now contains two keys "A" and "AX"
```

Then you can just loop through the fieldsValues dictionary and insert into your database at your heart's content.

Comment: Excellent, maybe add the foreach loop to the answer to help others, I have use this :
    foreach (var fieldsValue in fieldsValues)
    {
        <div>@fieldsValue.Key : @fieldsValue.Value</div>
    }